# db cant connect in php

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

I have a script where I need to connect to MySQL db. But somehow the connection is failed. Can anyone help me to check the problem? Thanks ahead.

```
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$hostname = "localhost";
$dbname = "vti_ctes_demo";

$con = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}else
{
    echo 'connected';   
}

// make foo the current db
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use vti_ctes_demo : ' . mysql_error());
}else
{
    echo 'connected';
}
```

The moment I run the query, I get this error:

```
Can't use vti_ctes_demo : Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'vti_ctes_demo'
```

I have set the username as 'root', but it seems like it can't receive the username. Btw, first connection is successful. Just that, the moment when it's connected to the db, then the error appeared.

Comment: Check this: string
$username
[optional]
The username. Default value is defined by mysql.default_user. In SQL safe mode, this parameter is ignored and the name of the user that owns the server process is used.

Comment: How am I going to check this? what should I do?

Comment: http://www.cpanelkb.net/sql-safe-mode-in-effect-errors/

Comment: somehow, the safe_mode is Off by default

Comment: Not sure what might be the issue then. Only explanation i found is safe mode enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You need grant privileges to the user "root" if you want external access to database vti_ctes_demo.

[Use this to grant permission to the user](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html)

Comment: Doubt that's the issue - seems like username isn't used to authenticate db user.